# call a swiffy object function with javascript?

Tags: actionscript-2, google-swiffy

I'm pretty new to javascript...
I have a swiffy object on my page and I need to load a given number of functions inside of it that I created in AS2.

```
setTimeout(function() { triggerP() },2000);
function triggerP()
{
    *what do I put here?*   
}
```

I wanted to call this function two seconds after the trigger has been fired, just not sure how to do it.

Comment: Only tried with AS3, here is my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255937/calling-a-flash-externalinterface-in-swiffyobject/19289669#19289669