# Calling a flash ExternalInterface in swiffyobject

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface, google-swiffy

I have a flash that communicates with a javascript using ExternalInterface. I have converted this into HTML5 using swiffy. How do call the methods i have created in flash using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the swiffy documentation, ExternalInterface is not supported for AS 2.0 or AS 3.0 by swiffy.

Please refer to:

- [ActionScript 2.0 support](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/actionscript2.html)
- [ActionScript 3.0 support](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/actionscript3.html)

Comment: These links are broken. They redirect back to Swiffy main page.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an update to the answer for who is still looking: 
As of now, Swiffy 5.3 has already supported ExternalInterface. I am able to make javascript call from AS3 using:

```
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunction", args);
```

In js, you just need to declare the "jsFunction" :

```
<script>
    function jsFunction(args) {
       alert("Call from AS3");
    }
</script>
```

For the reverse direction, calling from JS to AS3 through Swiffy can be achieved using this in AS3:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("nameForJS", closeFunction);
function closeFunction(s:String) {
    trace("Received " + s + " from js");
}
```

In JS, you will need to get the DOM el that tight to swiffy, and execute the function from there:

```
document.getElementById("swiffycontainer").nameForJS();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if it's also supported from AS2?

Answer (score 3):

Still, it is easy to call JavaScript function from AS3-to-HTML5-via-Swiffy :

```
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest( "javascript:doRoo();" );
navigateToURL( urlRequest,'_self' );
```

What is the best way to call a function that was declared in AS3 pre-swiffy from JavaScript - basically the reverse?